# How can I use command line arguments in the pom?

Tags: java, maven, command-line-interface, pom.xml

I've got a multi-module project that has a whole lot of bells & whistles. For example this plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.exec.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>python3</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>src/main/python</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>aggregate.py</argument>
                                <argument>${}</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

From the command line, we can pass flags like `-q` aka `--quiet`. For my second argument to `aggregate.py`, How do I pass in the `-q` flag or any other flags, into the python script, so it can also obey the log level request upon running?

It would of course be easy if we just used a custom param, but I want to use the built-in ones for a more seamless experience. How do I track `-q` or `--quiet`?

Answer (score 0):

You can take look at list of optional parameters for `exec-maven-plugin` - [list](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#quietLogs)

For `--quite` just add to to plugin configuration

```
<quietLogs>true</quietLogs>
```

Comment: I know I can add this, but I'd only want to add this if the `-q` flag was on--so how do I check if that is on in the pom?

Comment: I understand what you mean now. But am not sure if maven allows to propagate these cmd line options for custom use. one option to use different profiles.